# Программа для просмотра изображений, умеющая переходить между папками

Tags: windows

Есть фотоархив, в нем фотографии отсортированы в папки по датам. При просмотре программой ACDSee можно смотреть фото только в пределах одной папки, после просмотра последнего/первого фото из папки не происходит переход к просмотру следующей/предыдущей папки. Какой программой просмотра изображений можно смотреть фотоархив целиком, весь за раз, то есть какая программа сама умеет переключаться на соседние папки, чтобы не делать это вручную?

Для желающих отметить этот вопрос "не по теме" как
"Вопросы с просьбами предоставить рекомендации или найти книги, инструменты, библиотеки, материалы для обучения или любые другие внешние ресурсы являются на Stack Overflow вопросами не по теме, так как приводят к спорам и спаму. Вместо этого опишите проблему и что вы сделали для её решения."
**Описываю проблему** - я не знаю программы для просмотра изображений, умеющей переходить между папками.
**Что я сделал для ее решения** - просмотрел следующие программы: стандартный просмоторщик виндоус, acdsee 8 и 18, IrfanView, picasa - они не умеют.

Comment: А проводник пробовали? В режиме с preview pane.

Comment: @copenhagen при всем уважении к вашему упорству и пониманию особенностей SO, все таки вынужден закрыть ваш вопрос. Безусловно понимаю, что тема для вас актуальна, что вы не просто так ее задаете, но SO - это место где задаются вопросы касательно **программирования** и связанных с этим вопросов - в том числе настройки, администрирования и проч. Ваш вопрос не относится к этой категории. Удачи.

Comment: Я желаю закрыть этот вопрос как вопрос не по теме. Не потому что вы плохо описали проблему или испробованные вами способы её решения, а потому что ваш вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта. К сожалению, пока не готов перевод раздела справки "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы", но черновую версию вы можете найти [здесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/107/).